# Use stripe-mock with javascript client library (stripe-js, react-stripe-js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

On the backend (node) I can easily pass a `host` property to [stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) to connect to the locally running `stripe-mock` instance. ([sripe-mock](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock))

```
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_MOCK_SECRET_KEY, {
    apiVersion: '2022-08-01',
    host: process.env.STRIPE_MOCK_HOST,
    port: 12111,
    protocol: 'http',
  });
```

I am looking for the same functionality on the client side. I'm using [@stripe/stripe-js](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) and [@stripe/react-stripe-js](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js)

How do I tell the stripe javascript client to use my custom API URL?

Comment: Currently there isn't a utility to mock Stripe API requests from the client-side.  Is there a reason that simply using Test Mode transactions won't work for your use case?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply RyanM!
We want to have a `development` version of our system that is not dependent on external services. That's why Test Mode does not fully work for this. As a solution I now built it to skip payment altogether based on the environment.

Comment: Thank makes sense.  You can review the API calls that Stripe.js would make (things like requests to `/v1/{ payment | setup }_intents/{id}/confirm`) when confirming payments and stub those with your own responses.  You can use the API ref https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm and Stripe.js ref https://stripe.com/docs/js docs to get examples of the data that would be returned.